# Difference between XCTAssert and assert in Swift

Tags: testing, swift, assert

What's the difference between `XCTAssert()` and `assert()` in Swift?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`XCTAssert` is one of a family of asserts for unit testing from the `XCTest` framework, and should only be present in Unit Test Targets (i.e. not in your application code).  If the assert fails, it does not terminate the execution of the test harness or hosting application, but records and reports the failure.

Unit test assertions are recorded and reported during the "Test" action (compare to "Run" and "Install" actions).

`assert` is a debug-build-only swift assert for user code.  This can be present in your application or framework target bundles.  If the assert fails, the current application is stopped in a debuggable state, or terminated if not under the debugger.  Equivalent to Objective-C's `NSAssert`.  In release builds, the assert is ignored.

Comment: Ah interesting to know it is ignored in release builds. That could have caused me some headaches